# How to know if IEventProcessor is able to handle the event volume in Azure EventHub

Tags: azure-eventhub

I have multiple instances of `IEventProcessor` running but how do I tell whether to scale up or scale down to handle the event volume in EventHub? Which API should I call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the common techniques that is used is "tracking the event backlog", where you'll periodically read the properties of an Event Hub partition and compare the delta between the sequence number of the event that you're currently processing with that of the event last published to the partition.  While not a bulletproof and perfect approach, this provides a reasonable rough approach to understand if you're seeing events published at a greater rate than their being read when you track this across a few cycles.

While this is [available](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor/src/EventProcessorClientOptions.cs#L49) with the `EventProcessorClient` in the newer `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor` library, unfortunately, it doesn't appear as if the legacy `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs` processor exposes it.

If you're controlling your scaling through an orchestrator or other means not directly within your processor, then you may want to consider using the REST APIs.  The [Get Partition Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/get-partition-runtime-metadata) endpoint returns information about the size of the partition, the incoming/outgoing rates, and also the beginning/ending sequence numbers for comparison.